# Возможность прятать любой текст в вопросе

Tags: предложение

Бывает задаешь вопрос и предчувствуешь, что сейчас посыпятся: "А приведите код еще и оттуда...". Или начнут копаться в том, что уже работает.

Мне, например, не жалко выложить полный листинг проекта. Куча вопросов отпадет, а кому-то может вообще захочется скопировать код себе. Да и всегда лучшую помощь можно оказать когда знаешь чего хочет тот, кто задал вопрос.

**СУТЬ:** добавить бы возможность *спрятать часть вопроса, где будет полный листинг проекта* (если автор хочет поделится). Подразумеваю НЕ html (который уже так и работает), а С# например.

Если кто может ответить и так то этот код не будет ему мешать. А если кто захочет покопаться, то пожалуйста - нажимаешь "показать полностью".

---

PS: Пользователи StackOverflow часто относятся негативно ко всему, что находится "где-то там" (на другом ресурсе), а не на StackOverflow. Поэтому вместо ответа получаешь: "Какой ты нехороший человек, неужто не мог СЮДА все написать?" И по сути они абсолютно правы - а вдруг завтра тот ресурс накроется? От вопроса останутся "рожки да ножки".

Comment: [tag:статус-так-задумано] :) Полный листинг почти всегда плохо - потому что кроме автора в нем никто не может ориентироваться, особенно если проект большой

Comment: @Grundy, но так зря задумано ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, 30000 символов не так уж и мало :-) больше мне кажется будет совсем печально

Comment: @Grundy Тут СОГЛАСЕН с вами на 100%. Но если код работает, только дохнет. То проще показать полу-рабочее приложение, чтобы было понятно чего я ожидаю от него. Может я вообще задаю вопрос, ответ на который мне не поможет? (у меня было такое)

Comment: @Илья, перед показом нужно **локализовать** проблему. А не просто скинуть все что есть - "разбирайтесь чо там у меня не работает, ток я не скажу что этот код вообще делает" :)

Comment: На самом деле _А если кто захочет покопаться, то пожалуйста - нажимаешь "показать полностью"._ почти такое уже есть. Подробнее тут [Как сделать спойлер](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3525/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80/3526#3526) Но тот же самый лимит 30000 на сообщение и только для html+js+css

Comment: @Grundy Нет, я  так не делаю, проблему выделяю обязательно. Но похоже, что такая функция может плохо сказаться на качестве вопросов.

Comment: кроме сниппетов, есть несворачиваемые спойлеры - там любой язык можно, но естественно - запускать нельзя

Comment: А в чем проблема положить код куда-то в пастебин и дать в вопросе ссылку?

Comment: @avp, в том что ссылки могут протухать, это раз, количество кода по ссылке может быть весьма большим, это два

Comment: @Grundy, как раз потому, что количество кода большое, не нужно весь его класть в вопрос. А насчет того, что быстрее стухнет, SO или пастебин, это хороший вопрос.

Comment: @avp, ну так суть в том, что большое количество кода, что в самом вопросе, что по ссылке - это плохо.

Comment: @Grundy, если ограничиться конкретными вопросами, то да, если смотреть на программирование шире, то нет (иногда без полного кода не помочь (найдутся ли желающие? это другой вопрос)).